# 自分の質問に対して回答する場合、質問文はどのようにしたらいいですか

Tags: 討議

自分の質問に対して回答することは
誰かの役に立つ様に知識を共有しているため良いと思うのですが、

[区切り文字列を含めたまま分割する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16549/%E5%8C%BA%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE%E5%88%86%E5%89%B2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)　内での質問と回答のやりとりを見ました。

より広い視野を持った回答者から回答がついており、暗黙の条件や質問が不完全であることが指摘されていますが、
自己の努力の結果を共有する回答と、新しくついた回答、両方の整合性を保つことができる質問文にできますか？

Answer (score 1):

最初の質問文で誤って書いた"aaaa\nbbbb"を、回答者に改行を含む文字列として認識されてしまいました。
自分の回答は @"aaaa\nbbbb" を想定しています

sayuri さんに重複する改行などをどうするべきかという指摘で、質問文が誤りであることに気づきもともとの意図である文字列 @"aaaa\nbbbb" と書いて sayuri さんに回答のほうを修正して頂くつもりでした

その後、「put on hold as 質問内容がはっきりしない」というレビュー？の指摘があったので、改行が含まれているのが問題だと思いましたので、改行を含まない例文に変更し、合わせて自分の回答を変更しています
sayuri さんの回答が別のものになってしまいました

誤った質問文であったことは sayuri さんには本当に申し訳ないです
sayuri さんの回答を含め、この質問をどのように処理するべきか悩んでいます
この質問を一旦クローズして再度、正しい質問文で投稿したほうがよいでしょうか？

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。まとめを作っていてそういえば質問と回答を同時に投稿する場合の情報が少ないなと思っていたので助かります。

Comment: `\n`から`,`に変わってしまったせいか的外れな回答になってしまい-2されてしまいました。変更に対応する過程で別のアプローチを見つけましたので、全面的に修正しました。新規に投稿する必要はなく、修正された質問文をもって再オープンしていただけたらと思います。